# Dovecot Not Attempting to Authenticate Clients Centos 7

Tags: email-server, centos7, dovecot

We have just installed our email but the system is not recognising client log in attempts, in the mail log the message 'Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>' is displayed.

The server is Centos 7 on a Verelox server.

dovecot -n:

```
[root@mail log]# dovecot -n
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_uid = 1000
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = no
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

postconf -n

```
[root@mail log]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 10485760
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = xxxxxx.net
myhostname = mail.xxxxxxx.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
[root@mail log]#
```

Logs:

```
Jul  7 10:15:49 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, session=<8RFuhLdTPgBe0Qq7>
Jul  7 10:17:58 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, session=<ODQajLdTSgBe0Qq7>
Jul  7 10:17:58 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, session=<qjUajLdTSABe0Qq7>
Jul  7 10:17:58 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, session=<ykUajLdTTABe0Qq7>
Jul  7 10:17:58 mail dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, session=<nUYajLdTTgBe0Qq7>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try authenticating manually by connecting to the server through `openssl s_client` or `telnet` (depending on whether you configured TLS). What's the output? Also enable debug logging, at least for authentication (["The most important thing to do is to set `auth_debug=yes`, and preferrably also `auth_debug_passwords=yes`"](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Debugging/Authentication)).

Comment: Hello,  Telnet is working fine see result here:telnet mail.domain.net 25
Trying 185.143.240.32...
Connected to mail.domain.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.domain.net ESMTP
ehlo localhost
250-mail.domain.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10485760
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Port 25 is SMTP, not IMAP. And do not only try to connect, but also login ([Wikipedia has nice examples for most relevant protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol#Dialog_example)).

Comment: Hello I have enabled the debug and now i get this in log: Jul  7 22:30:47 mail dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xx.xxx.xx.xxx, lip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, session=<nM/nyMFTjABe0Qq7>
Jul  7 22:33:48 mail dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul  7 22:33:48 mail dovecot: anvil: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Jul  7 22:33:48 mail dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill).

Comment: Telnet with localhost and domain with imap port is not working see result [root@mail log]# telnet localhost 110
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@mail log]# telnet localhost 143
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@mail log]#... what can be the problem?

Comment: Please don't put code and logs (and generally no relevant information) in the comments, they're barely readable here with all linebreaks removed. Edit your question instead. Additionally, make sure that something is listening on ports 143 and 110 (`netstat -pan | grep LISTEN | grep -E '(110|143)'`).

Answer (score 0):

`ssl = no`

Probably isn't helping.
Check the pathnames and that the cert and key are actually there, too.